# How can you customize the numbers in an ordered list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, roman-numerals

How can I left-align the numbers in an ordered list?

```
1.  an item
// skip some items for brevity 
9.  another item
10. notice the 1 is under the 9, and the item contents also line up
```

Change the character after the number in an ordered list?

```
1) an item
```

Also is there a CSS solution to change from numbers to alphabetic/roman lists instead of using the type attribute on the ol element.

I am mostly interested in answers that work on Firefox 3.

Comment: a very elegant example with nesting! --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters#example_of_a_nested_counter

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This is the solution I have working in Firefox 3, Opera and Google Chrome. The list still displays in IE7 (but without the close bracket and left align numbers):

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(item) ") ";
  counter-increment: item;
  width: 2em;
  margin-left: -2em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine<br>Items</li>
  <li>Ten<br>Items</li>
</ol>
```

**EDIT:** Included multiple line fix by strager

> Also is there a CSS solution to change from numbers to alphabetic/roman lists instead of using the type attribute on the ol element.

Refer to [list-style-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#lists) CSS property. Or when using counters the second argument accepts a list-style-type value. For example the following will use upper roman:

```
li::before {
  content: counter(item, upper-roman) ") ";
  counter-increment: item;
/* ... */
```

Comment: Needed to add the numbers back in, a global style was removing them (who knows why you would use a ol and remove the numbers rather than a  ul??). Very clear answer +1 for full explanation and code, can easily be modified to do anything.

Comment: I suggest a cleaner CSS *margin/padding* solution, that works better with lists having wide numbering: `ol {counter-reset: item; 
padding-left: 0;} li {display: block; margin-bottom: .5em;} li:before {display: inline-block; content: counter(item) ") "; counter-increment: item; padding-right: 0.8em;}`.

Answer (score 52):

## HTML5: Use the `value` attribute (no CSS needed)

Modern browsers will interpret the `value` attribute and will display it as you expect. See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attr-value).

```html
<ol>
  <li value="3">This is item three.</li>
  <li value="50">This is item fifty.</li>
  <li value="100">This is item one hundred.</li>
</ol>
```

Also have a look at [the `<ol>` article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol), especially the documentation for the `start` and attribute.

Comment: but is there any way to style, say, the `font-family` of the numbers?

Comment: This needs more upvotes, perfect solution, thank you!

Answer (score 31):

The CSS for styling lists is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/generate.html#lists), but is basically:

```css
li {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

However, the specific layout you're after can probably only be achieved by delving into the innards of the layout with something like [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/generate.html#counters) (note that I haven't actually tried it):

```css
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counter(item) ") "; counter-increment: item }
```

Comment: This gets the numbers lined up, but the text content isn't.

Answer (score 16):

You can also specify your own numbers in the HTML - e.g. if the numbers are being provided by a database:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: attr(seq) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li seq="1">Item one</li>
  <li seq="20">Item twenty</li>
  <li seq="300">Item three hundred</li>
</ol>
```

The `seq` attribute is made visible using a method similar to that given in other answers. But instead of using `content: counter(foo)`, we use `content: attr(seq)`.

[Demo in CodePen with more styling](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGMERG)

Comment: You can simplify this if you just use the `value` attribute on `<li>`. e.g. `<li value="20">`. Then you don't need any pseudo elements. [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPbZJM)

Comment: @GWB While that is valid (and a good solution), it's limited to numerical values as the list is ordinal. As such, you can't do something like `value="4A"`, as it won't work. Additionally, the value attribute can work with the `type` attribute, but value still must be a number (as it works within an ordered set).

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me when I needed [Flying Saucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) to show a list in reverse order (`reversed` attribute is html5 only, as is using the `value` of the `li`). Instead of using your `seq` I set a `value` and used `attr(value)` instead of `attr(seq)`

Comment: Is `seq` a standard attribute defined anywhere? If not, wouldn't it be better to use data-seq?

Answer (score 8):

Stole a lot of this from other answers, but this is working in FF3 for me. It has `upper-roman`, uniform indenting, a close bracket.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(item, upper-roman) ")";
  counter-increment: item;
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest playing with the :before attribute and seeing what you can achieve with it. It will mean your code really is limited to nice new browsers, and excludes the (annoyingly large) section of the market still using rubbish old browsers,

Something like the following, which forces a fixed with on the items. Yes, I know it's less elegant to have to choose the width yourself, but using CSS for your layout is like undercover police work: however good your motives, it always gets messy.

```
li:before {
  content: counter(item) ") ";
  counter-increment: item;
  display: marker;
  width: 2em;
}
```

But you're going to have to experiment to find the exact solution.

Comment: you'll need a counter-reset: item; before that block.

Answer (score 5):

The numbers line up better if you add leading-zeroes to the numbers, by setting [list-style-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type) to:

```
ol { list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Borrowed and improved [Marcus Downing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list#10887).  Tested and works in Firefox 3 and Opera 9.  Supports multiple lines, too.

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 3.5em;          /* Change with margin-left on li:before.  Must be -li:before::margin-left + li:before::padding-right.  (Causes indention for other lines.) */
}

li:before {
    content: counter(item) ")";  /* Change 'item' to 'item, upper-roman' or 'item, lower-roman' for upper- and lower-case roman, respectively. */
    counter-increment: item;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 3em;                  /* Must be the maximum width of your list's numbers, including the ')', for compatability (in case you use a fixed-width font, for example).  Will have to beef up if using roman. */
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -3.5em;         /* See li comments. */
}
```

Comment: Also you want text-align: left; not right. And the last line should be margin-left: -3.5em;

Comment: @grom, Thanks for the em correction.  Also, Opera renders lists right-aligned by default, so I mimicked this behavior.

Comment: @grom, The Firefox issue is ...  Firefox puts the li:before pseudoelement on its own line without the float, even if it is display: inline-block.

Comment: @strager, Well I am using 3.0.4 on Linux and 3.0.3 on Windows, and it works for me without the float: left; rule.

Comment: @grom, Hmm, interesting.  I just tested myself, and it works without the float.  Maybe I mistyped.

Answer (score 2):

Nope... just use a DL:

```
dl { overflow:hidden; }
dt {
 float:left;
 clear: left;
 width:4em; /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
 text-align: right
}
dd {
 float:left;
 width:50%; /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
 margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Type attribute](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_OL_TYPE.html) which allows you to change the numbering style, however, you cannot change the full stop after the number/letter.

```
<ol type="a">
    <li>Turn left on Maple Street</li>
    <li>Turn right on Clover Court</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: The markup in this answer needs to be fixed. Use lowercase and enclose attribute values in "quotes".

Comment: And close your elements: <li>...</li>.

Comment: @dylanfm — You are aware that the markup presented is proper, 100% valid HTML, yes? Don't downvote people for not using XHTML unless XHTML is requested.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. And yes, that's true re. HTML. I was just being a standardsy picky person.

Comment: My apologies for posting invalid html. I copied the code from a website and didn't think to correct it. I feel ashamed now :(

Answer (score 1):

The docs say regarding [`list-style-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position)`: outside`

> CSS1 did not specify the precise location of the marker box and for reasons of compatibility, CSS2 remains equally ambiguous. For more precise control of marker boxes, please use markers.

Further up that page is the stuff about markers.

One example is:

```
       LI:before { 
           display: marker;
           content: "(" counter(counter) ")";
           counter-increment: counter;
           width: 6em;
           text-align: center;
       }
```

Comment: All the examples (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#q11) for markers do not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirt** alternative solution. You can use a tabulation character along with preformatted text. Here's a possibility:

```
<style type="text/css">
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
li:first-letter {
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>
```

and your html:

```
<ol>
<li>    an item</li>
<li>    another item</li>
...
</ol>
```

Note that the space between the `li` tag and the beggining of the text is a tabulation character (what you get when you press the tab key inside notepad).

If you need to support older browsers, you can do this instead:

```
<style type="text/css">
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
</style>

<ol>
    <li><pre>   </pre>an item</li>
    <li><pre>   </pre>another item</li>
    ...
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give here the kind of answer i usually don't like to read, but i think that as there are other answers telling you how to achive what you want, it could be nice to rethink if what you are trying to achive is really a good idea.

First, you should think if it is a good idea to show the items in a non-standard way, with a separator charater diferent than the provided.

I don't know the reasons for that, but let's suppose you have good reasons.

The ways propossed here to achive that consist in add content to your markup, mainly trough the CSS :before pseudoclass. This content is really modifing your DOM structure, adding those items to it.

When you use standard "ol" numeration, you will have a rendered content in which the "li" text is selectable, but the number preceding it is not selectable. That is, the standard numbering system seems to be more "decoration" than real content. If you add content for numbers using for example those ":before" methods, this content will be selectable, and dued to this, performing undesired vopy/paste issues, or accesibility issues with screen readers that will read this "new" content in addition to the standard numeration system.

Perhaps another approach could be to style the numbers using images, although this alternative will bring its own problems (numbers not shown when images are disabled, text size for number not changing, ...).

Anyway, the reason for this answer is not just to propose this "images" alternative, but to make people think in the consequences of trying to change the standard numeration system for ordered lists.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes numbering style same as headers of li content.

```
<style>
    h4 {font-size: 18px}
    ol.list-h4 {counter-reset: item; padding-left:27px}
    ol.list-h4 > li {display: block}
    ol.list-h4 > li::before {display: block; position:absolute;  left:16px;  top:auto; content: counter(item)"."; counter-increment: item; font-size: 18px}
    ol.list-h4 > li > h4 {padding-top:3px}
</style>

<ol class="list-h4">
    <li>
        <h4>...</h4>
        <p>...</p> 
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vhndaree [posted an interesting implementation of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70835307/2756409) problem on a duplicate question, which goes a step further than any of the existing answers in that it implements a custom character *before* the incrementing numbers:

> ```css
>  
>  .custom {
>      list-style-type: none;
>  }
>  .custom li {
>      counter-increment: step-counter;
>  }
>  .custom li::before {
>      content: '(' counter(step-counter) ')';
>      margin-right: 5px;
>  }
> ```
>
> ```html
>  
>  <ol class="custom">
>     <li>First</li>
>     <li>Second</li>
>     <li>Third</li>
>     <li>Fourth</li>
>     <li>Fifth</li>
>     <li>Sixth</li>
>     <li>Seventh</li>
>     <li>Eighth</li>
>     <li>Ninth</li>
>     <li>Tenth</li>
>  </ol>
> ```

Answer (score -1):

I have it. Try the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>

    ol { counter-reset: item; }

    li { display: block; }

    li:before { content: counter(item) ")"; counter-increment: item; 
        display: inline-block; width: 50px; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
</ol>
</body>
```

The catch is that this *definitely* won't work on older or less compliant browsers: `display: inline-block` is a very new property.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are better from a conceptual point of view.  However, you can just left-pad the numbers with the appropriate number of '&ensp;' to make them line up.

*** Note: I did not at first recognize that a numbered list was being used.  I thought the list was being explicitly generated.