# specifing text as bullets in list

Tags: php, html, css

I know in HTML you can use `<ol><li></li></ol>` to get a nice ordered list but doing that with list-style-type: decimal always increments the number by 1.

I'm looking for a way to set the value of the bullet text.

I might end up with a list that looks something like

12  item
22  item
 2  item

I don't want to do any crazy use of images if at all possible.
Is there an easy solution for this?

I have HTML, CSS, javascript (jquery) and PHP available.

Comment: Might the data be considered tabular? In which case, a table might do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't really an **ordered** list then is it? You should just emulate a bullet in an unordered list:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>22</span> item
</ul>
```

Remove the bullet with `list-style-type: none` then style to taste.

Comment: Yes, you're right....I'm switching your <span> for a <div> and doing a little aligning so I can get the bullets right justified and the text left justified.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SOFlow: [Is it possible to specify a starting number for an ordered list with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779016/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-starting-number-for-an-ordered-list-with-css)

[Make OL list start from number different than 1 using CSS](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/make-ol-list-start-from-number-different-than-1-using-css.html). Other than that, the only way to accomplish this is through fancy positioning. This is one of those things I wish they hadn't deprecated.

Comment: From your link I tried adding style="counter-reset: item ##;" to the `<ol>` but that didn't do the trick.  I found the start="##" and that works...except that it's deprecated :-(

Comment: Like I said, I wish they hadn't deprecated it :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick.  However, be aware that value is a deprecated attribute for the li tag in HTML 4.

```
<ol>
<li value="12">item</li>
<li value="22">item</li>
<li value="2">item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why's all the useful stuff deprecated :-(

Comment: value attribute is deprecated

Comment: The value attribute is not deprecated anymore in HTML5: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-li-element