# Customized counter-reset: item

Tags: html, css

How can I customize the numbers created when using the following CSS:

```
div.Most ol{counter-reset: item;}
div.Most ol li:before {content: counter(item) "  "; counter-increment: item}
```

By adding these lines to my ordered list, I obtain a numerical value starting from zero to the number of items in my list. What I want is to control the values manually. Say I want the first item to have value 2 and the second 4 and so forth.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible but you should avoid logics in your CSS. I suggest Javascript instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify a starting number for an ordered list with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779016/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-starting-number-for-an-ordered-list-with-css)

Comment: okey what about decimal values ranging between 0.1 and 0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to always increment by 2, you can set that as the `counter-increment` value:

```
div.Most ol li:before {content: counter(item) "  "; counter-increment: item 2}
```

This is documented in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-counter-increment).