# ol cannot be started from specific count

Tags: html, css

For reasons of styling I use an ol element with pseudo classes. Unfortunately I cannot start counting the list items from a desired index. What is wrong?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4m5utr8/1)

HTML

```
<ol start="14">
    <li>car</li>
    <li>flower</li>
    <li>garden</li>
    <li>shool</li>
    <li>river</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol {
    width: 850px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(item)" ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify a starting number for an ordered list with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779016/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-starting-number-for-an-ordered-list-with-css)

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard Not really a duplicate. This question is regarding CSS counters.

Comment: @Second Rikudo The `start` attribute is irrelevant when using counters. That confused me. I see the difference.

Comment: `counter-reset` takes a number: http://jsfiddle.net/h4m5utr8/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the start value in `counter-reset`:

```
counter-reset: item 13;
```

Unfortunately, current browsers don't support accessing to the attribute values, so something like `counter-reset: item calc(attr(start) - 1);` won't work. You have to set the value explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are resetting the index with the css rule `counter-reset: item`

To get your desired results use `counter-reset: item 13`

check out teh updated fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/h4m5utr8/3/