# "Halt" ordered list numbering

Tags: css, html-lists

I got inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30109692/15576971) answer on another topic and tried to utilize it in my own situation in order to get rid of having to manually insert some `start=x` in some `ol`'s in a page, but my situation is far more complex than that one, so I can't make it work exactly how I want...

So I have some `ol`'s, each one following an `h3` tag. Now, the hard part is that there may be some `li`'s that shouldn't get an ordering, and on top of that, there may exist some `ol`'s with just one `li` inside, where that single `li` shouldn't get an ordering either...

So it's like:

```
<h3>Some title</h3>
<ol>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li class="no-style">Second item that shouldn't get ordered and shouldn't increment the next item either</li>
    <li>Third item, ordered with number 2</li>
</ol>
<h3>Some other title</h3>
<ol>
    <li>Another list's first item</li>
    <li>Another list's second item</li>
    <li>Another list's third item</li>
</ol>
<h3>And yet another title</h3>
<ol>
   <li>A single item here that shouldn't get ordered</li>
</ol>
```

So the above code should produce the following result:

```
Some title
  1. One item
     Second item that shouldn't get ordered and shouldn't increment the next item either
  2. Third item, ordered with number 2
Some other title
  1. Another list's first item
  2. Another list's second item
  3. Another list's third item
And yet another title
     A single item here that shouldn't get ordered
```

So I experimented with many variations of the following CSS, but nothing worked the way it should:

```
li:only-of-type, li.no-style { list-style-type: none; }
h3 + ol { counter-reset: mycounter; }
h3 + ol > li:not(.no-style) + li:before, h3 + ol > li:first-of-type:not(.no-style):before { counter-increment: mycounter; } 
h3 + ol > li:not(.no-style):before { content: counter(mycounter) ". "; }
```

Basically, the idea is to `counter-increment` `mycounter` only when the previous `li` doesn't have the class `no-style`, and also, make the whole numbering disappear when the `li` is the `only-of-type`...

I hope, as soon as I catch some sleep since it's too late in my timezone and I'm exhausted, that I'll be able to get this to work, unless someone expert in CSS gets to find the correct syntax first, and can help me a little bit.

Thanks in advance for any possible help that I receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then perhaps these examples below can help you somehow. You can combine both solutions completely for your needs.

**Example #1.**
By default, lists have `display: list-item;` To simply disable the intermediate element, it is enough to assign it `display: block;` (or any other), as can be seen in the example:

```css
h3 + ol > li:only-child,
.no-style {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Some title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>One item</li>
  <li class="no-style">Second item that shouldn't get ordered and shouldn't increment the next item either</li>
  <li>Third item, ordered with number 2</li>
</ol>
<h3>Some other title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>Another list's first item</li>
  <li>Another list's second item</li>
  <li>Another list's third item</li>
</ol>
<h3>And yet another title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>A single item here that shouldn't get ordered</li>
</ol>
```

**Example #2.** If you need full control over the counters, then you will have to use properties such as (`counter-increment`, `counter-reset`, etc.). Example below:

```css
li:only-of-type,
li.no-style {
  list-style-type: none;
}

h3 + ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: mycounter;
}

h3 + ol > li:before {
  counter-increment: mycounter;
  content: counter(mycounter) ". ";
}

h3 + ol > li:only-child:before,
.no-style:before {
  counter-increment: none !important;
  content: "0. " !important; /* hold the indent */
  list-style-type: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h3>Some title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>One item</li>
  <li class="no-style">Second item that shouldn't get ordered and shouldn't increment the next item either</li>
  <li>Third item, ordered with number 2</li>
</ol>
<h3>Some other title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>Another list's first item</li>
  <li>Another list's second item</li>
  <li>Another list's third item</li>
</ol>
<h3>And yet another title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>A single item here that shouldn't get ordered</li>
</ol>
```

To cancel the increment in a specific selector, it is enough to use `counter-increment: none;`.

For elements that are the only ones in their parent, you can use the pseudo-class [:only-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child).

Comment: Similar to the other answer, your answer is also great in the sense that the numbering is exactly as I wanted it to be. But again, 1., 2., etc take up space from the first line of the `li`, whereas ideally I'd like them to be on the left of the text contained in the `li`, just like it happens in a stock `li`. Is there a way to preserve that somehow?

Comment: @FayeD. I have updated my answer for you. If everything should work as a simple list, with the default behavior, then you can simply disable one element from the list by adding the `display: block` property to it, or so on. There is an example in the response.

Comment: This is unbelievably apocalyptic... I literally got carried away by the other topic I shared in my question, and didn't try the easiest and most obvious... Thank you so-so-so very much for this one-liner solution! That was EXACTLY what I was after! God bless you!

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the counter only on those items which are to show the counter.

To put in our own 'marker' we have to get rid of all the standard markers and instead allow space for them ourselves which this snippet does by setting a width to a before pseudo element on every list item.

```css
/* we start a new counter for every ol */

h3+ol {
  counter-reset: mycounter;
}


/* don't show the standard marker */

h3+ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}


/* Now we increment the counter on every li except if it's the only one  or is in the no-style class */


/* and we show the counter on every li */

h3+ol li:not(:only-of-type):not(.no-style)::before {
  content: counter(mycounter) ". ";
  counter-increment: mycounter;
}

h3+ol li::before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 2em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

```html
<h3>Some title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>One item</li>
  <li class="no-style">Second item that shouldn't get ordered and shouldn't increment the next item either</li>
  <li>Third item, ordered with number 2</li>
</ol>
<h3>Some other title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>Another list's first item</li>
  <li>Another list's second item</li>
  <li>Another list's third item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
<h3>And yet another title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>A single item here that shouldn't get ordered</li>
</ol>
```

Note: the amount you might want to save for the counter may depend on how big it is going to get. This snippet has allowed a couple of em width. If you had hundreds of items you'd want to save more space for the counter probably.

Comment: Your answer is great in the sense that indeed the numbering is exactly as I wanted it to be. The only thing I don't like is the indentation, where the 1., 2., etc take up space from the first line of the `li`, whereas default numbers are rendered outside (on the left) of the text contained in the `li`. Is there a way to preserve that somehow?

Ah, additionally, in your sample code, you omitted the `>` combinator for adjacent children, affecting any nested `li`'s inside the `ol`. For example in some `ol` -> `li`'s, I have a `ul` -> `li`'s, that were also affected.

Comment: Use position absolute rather than relative if you don't want the list to be moved - but I thought you'd want it to look like a normal list from that POV. On the selection, yes if it's not to apply to nested ols then you need more specificity.

Comment: But that's exactly how I want it to look: Like a normal list! And normally list numbers are rendered outside of the text in the `li`! https://jsfiddle.net/princeofabyss/46zxrvuk/ https://i.ibb.co/GpDTpt9/Screenshot-2022-01-07-202104.jpg