# I want to change the list style to numbers that i want

Tags: css

So, I've tried to change it and I found a way but I don't think that's the correct way, because I changed every single "li".

Is there a  professional way?

and thanks

```css
.ul-list {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: black;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ul-list .ol-html {
  margin: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.ul-list .ol-html #slim::before {
  content: counter(number) ".";
  counter-increment: number 10;
}

.ul-list .ol-html #pugjs::before {
  content: counter(number) ".";
  counter-increment: number 11;
}

.ul-list .ol-html #haml::before {
  content: counter(number) ".";
  counter-increment: number 12;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-list">
  <li>
    HTML
    <ol class="ol-html">
      <li id="slim">Slim</li>
      <li id="pugjs">Pugjs</li>
      <li id="haml">HAML</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you just want to change start number, see [this(Is it possible to specify a starting number for an ordered list?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779016/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-starting-number-for-an-ordered-list)

Comment: yes, and thank you very much, i've found the answer and it's like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any styles to your lists, it can be numbers, emojis

```css
li {
  list-style-type: thumbs;
}

@counter-style thumbs {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols:   ;
  suffix: " ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><i class="bi bi-check"></i> Buy Milk</li>
  <li><i class="bi bi-check"></i> Buy Egg</li>
  <li><i class="bi bi-check"></i> Buy Bread</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was trying to do a counter start from 10 but using CSS only

Comment: @Abdalmalkkasem in that case you can use `start` attribute in your `ol`. For example `<ol start="10">...</ol>`

Comment: and with CSS you can check this link https://jsfiddle.net/m8uhoatc/6/

Answer (score 1):

If your goal it's to start the counter for the `ol.ol-html` at 10 you can use the `start` attribute on the `ol`

```css
.ul-list {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: black;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ul-list .ol-html {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-list">
  <li>
    HTML
    <ol class="ol-html" start="10">
      <li id="slim">Slim</li>
      <li id="pugjs">Pugjs</li>
      <li id="haml">HAML</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know i can, but I was trying to do it using CSS

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

So if we want to start attributing for an ordered list using only CSS
we will use `counter-increment` property.

Example:

```css
  ol {
      list-style: none;
      counter-increment:start 9;
}

   li::before {
      content: counter(start, decimal) ". ";
      counter-increment: start;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ol>
```

so here `counter-increment` it's 0-indexed,
so to get a list that starts at 10, use 9