# arrange the ol list numbers to the left side

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to arrange the ol list numbers (2 digit numbers) to start from the left side.

Usually it comes like this

```
1
2
.
.
10
12
```

But I need that to show like this

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The numbers float to the right by default: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/UG5Y4/1/

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/489088/364869).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can use **counter -increment** for this. Write like this:

```
ul{    counter-reset: chapter 0;  }
li:before{    
    counter-increment: chapter;    
    content:counter(chapter) ". ";
    width:20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;   
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/upc6b/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS counters:

**CSS**:

```
ol {
    padding-left: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: number;
}

ol li:before {
    display: inline-block;

    content: counter(number) '.';
    counter-increment: number;

    width: 30px;
}
```

The only problem with this approach is that the width of the number area is fixed, so it will not expand as the number of elements grows.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/UG5Y4/2/**

Comment: Counters are not new to CSS3.

Comment: @BoltClock: Huh, I always thought they were. Thanks for the tip!