# CSS position <li> elements

Tags: css

```
<div class="oringal">
    <ul class="rank">
<li class="rank-1">
    <img src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/packaging_design/Tetra_pak_New_packaging_Juice7_by_KATOK.jpg" />
    <p>1</p>
</li>
<li class="rank-2">
    <img src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/packaging_design/21.jpg" />
    <p>2</p>
</li>
```

I want to get the ranking sequence as follows, but i do not want change the html, how can i just change the css in the div.oringal to get the ranking sequence as follows.first in center, second rights, third lefts

please see the full code on jsfiddle page http://jsfiddle.net/6grsm/1/, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

"*i want get the sequence 3 1 2, but i do not want to change the sequence in html in div.original, my question is, how should i change the css*"

From that comment, it seems that what you actually is *not* to change the positioning of elements, but change the order of numbering, which is a completely different question.  The easiest way to do this is to use the (deprecated, but still seemingly supported) `start` attribute of the `ol` tag.  In CSS, you can also set `counter-increment` for `li` tags, which will enable customisation of what the li tags display.  Examples of the various methods are in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using absolute positioning.  It looks like you are creating a shopping cart layout so I assume that you have a fairly structured page to start with.

See demo at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/rC59T/

Your HTML is basically this:

```
<div calss="panel-wrap">
<ul  class="rank">
    <li class="rank-1">
        <img ... />
        <p>1</p>
    </li>
    <li class="rank-2">
        <img ... />
        <p>2</p>
    </li>
    <li class="rank-3">
        <img ... />
        <p>3</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
.panel-wrap {
    width: 460px; 
}
```

The `.panel-wrap` is useful if you want to add background images and so on.

```
ul.rank {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative; /* this will force the li to be positioned with respect
                           to this block level container */
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 200px;
}
ul.rank li {
    width: 150px;
    top: 0;           /* pin top and bottom so that the li fills in the height
                         of the parent container */
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
}
ul.rank img {
    width: 150px; 
    xheight: 90px; /* Careful not to adjust both width and height which could
                      distort your images */
}
ul.rank p {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;    /* pin left and right so the p fills in the 
                   width of the li... */
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The trick is to adjust the left offset for each list item in uniformly spaced increments:

```
.rank-3 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.rank-1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 160px;
}
.rank-2 {
    top: 0;
    left: 320px;
}
```

**The Big Advantage**

What you could do is set the left offset dynamically using JavaScript/jQuery, and create an interactive page where the user can click buttons and scroll through a series of catalog items.

Comment: IMHO, using absolute positioning to brute-force things to happen when there are valid HTML / CSS rules to achieve the same results isn't very good practice

Comment: For a colonial effort, it's not too shabby... absolute positioning is valid CSS, it can solve some problems.  The original post is a bit open ended, so maybe this may fit the bill.

Comment: I'm not saying absolute positioning isn't CSS (it is, and I use it a lot), but there are tools specifically for what he is trying to do, as far as I can work out :)