# Skipping items with CSS counters

Tags: css

I'm using CSS counters to try to build this ordered list:

```
X.
Y.
Z.
AA.
BB.
CC.
```

So far, I've got this:

```
X.
Y.
Z.
AA.
AB.
AC.
```

In the html, I have to skip ahead 26 items to get from AA to BB, instead of AA to AB. Apparently, CSS counters don't take into consideration the `value="54"` attribute in the `<li>` tag.

Anyone know of a way to handle this without having to create another `<ol>` that starts at BB?

There was a similar question, but the answer isn't quite there.
[How can you customize the numbers in an ordered list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list)

Thanks!
- Michael M.

Comment: Why are you using counters? That seems to be pretty well accomplished by `<ol type="A">`. (For some values of “well”.) Also, is this for a spreadsheet-like device? Generate them with JavaScript…

Comment: The type is decimal, so no need for that attribute.  I never knew about that html attribute.  I've been setting my lists as CSS list-style-type.  Also, it's not a spreadsheet, so this isn't a task for js. Thanks for reading my question though, I appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, I misread `value="54"` as `start="54"`. So what element is `value="54"` on?

Comment: No problem.  It's on the li element.  That would work in straight html, but I'm using CSS.  The response below from Kalley did the trick.  Thanks for taking interest in my question, minitech.

Comment: You can also use `value` attr. with attribute selectors, like http://jsfiddle.net/XRhSQ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's something that works: http://jsfiddle.net/8PKjj/1/

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item 23;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: counter(item, upper-alpha) '.';
    position: absolute;
    left: -2em;
}
li.big-jump:before {
    counter-increment: item 27;
}
```

It's not the prettiest thing, but it's a place to start.