# How to style OL number points in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to pretty up my order list items and I'm now wondering how I can achieve the following effect, and if it's even possible in pure CSS:

[image]

Is it possible to change the number-points and style them like this in just CSS, and if so, how?

Comment: already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list

Comment: Didn't see that when I searched SO.

Comment: Using background-image is not a solution since the moment the length of the numbers is greater than the width of the image, you're stuffed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a combination of the `:before` pseudo element and [CSS counter-increment](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp).

The HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
</ol>
```

And the CSS:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: li;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* Style the before element how you want, the important bits here are the content element and counter-increment */
li:before {
    width: 1.75em;
    height: 1.75em;
    position: absolute; left: 0;        
    margin-right: 12px;       
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie but this totally blows in IE 11. The numbers overlap the first letter of each list item. And there is no other styling either.

Comment: @jay_t55 Sure, that's because I didn't include any styling in my example, I just gave you the code to get it working. Style li:before in any way you want, so looking at your question you can add a background-color, 50% border radius etc etc.

Comment: Oh sorry I totally forgot. I need to sleep more. Im' gonna go style it now. :)

Comment: @jay_t55 Don't worry, we've all been there!

Comment: Just a little mucking around I got http://jsfiddle.net/e56281vj/28/ some circles there. Thanks @Jamie. :) Now I just need to tweak it a little more.