# Javascript & HTML - Place <ol> number after <li> title

Tags: javascript, html

On my test page I've set it up to create an `<li>` element inside an `<ol>` when a `<button>` is pressed. Let's say the list title is `"Problem"`. Instead of 
`"1. Problem"`, I'd like it to be `"Problem 1."`. Is there a way to put the `<ol>` digit after the list title?

```
        <form>                                              
            <button type="button" id="btn_add_task" class="btn btn-primary" title="Lägg till fler att-satser.">+</button>       
        </form>           

            <ol id="list_tasks" style="font-style:italic; font-size: 18pt; padding: 0">
            </ol> 

            <script>            
                function $(element) {
                    return document.getElementById(element);
                }

                var taskSubmit = $('btn_add_task');
                var taskBox = $('text_task');
                var taskList = $('list_tasks');

                taskSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var att = 'att';
                    var attNum = 1;

                    var newLI = document.createElement('li');
                    var newText = document.createElement('textarea');

                    newLI.appendChild(document.createTextNode(att + attNum + ': '));                    

                    spanNum.id = 'val';
                    newLI.id = 'list';
                    newText.className = 'attText';
                    newText.rows = 1;

                    taskList.appendChild(newLI);
                    taskList.appendChild(newText);

                }, false);
            </script>
```

Comment: any code? what you tried? We need to know more...

Comment: but it seems like a css pseudo :after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from responses to [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list) on customizing `<ol>` list elements.
You can put various things in the `li:before` pseudo-element, but you need to play w/the margins and padding a bit to ensure things line up & are properly spaced.

- Left margin for the `li` itself can be used to indent & align the text content.
- Left margin for `li:before` is negative & equal to left margin of `li`
- Width of the `li:before` must accommodate the full width of the leading number & other content.
- Padding of `li:before` sets the distance between "Problem #." and the text itself.
- Text-alignment `left` of `li:before` keeps "Problem" aligned regardless how many numbers you have.

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
 
}

li:before {
    content: "Problem "counter(item) ".";  
    counter-increment: item;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 5em;                  
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -5.5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine<br>Items</li>
  <li>Ten<br>Items</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest would be

```
<ol dir="rtl">
```

Comment: Can't do that. It will change too much.

Comment: Don't know. When I tried rtl for only li, the number is way over to the right. If we can put the number closer to the normal title that'd be great :D

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
ol[dir=rtl] {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Then HTML would be

```
<ol dir="rtl">
 <li>Problem</li>
 <li>Something else</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Nope sorry, read previous answer about the same thing. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: But this CSS brings the number close to the text like you asked.

Comment: Oh sorry missed that part, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution just with CSS:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adVPrN

HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: li;
}
ol li:after {
  counter-increment: li;
  content: " " counter(li) ".";
}
```

And here the MDN site for the CSS counter:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters