# CSS select first character in list item

Tags: html, css

I have a page with about 10 lists, 5 are unordered and 5 are ordered. Rather than the generic disc or bullet/number or Roman numeral I've decided to make up a custom list marker. Each list item is as so...

```
<ul>
  <li>*List Item 1</li>
  <li>*List Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ol>
  <li>1List Item</li>
  <li>1List Item</li>
</ol>
```

What I need to do is select the initial character being 1, 2 or *. Without using span 100 times or separate stylings for `ul` and `ol`, is there a way to select the first character.

I have tried using spans but with that many lists and list items there becomes a lot of extra coding...I've also tried
    li::first-letter {...}
This works for the ul, but for `ol` it results in e.g. "*L" from "*List Item".

I've read a little into ":before", this would probably be the next best thing but I'm hoping there's a selector to do all li's.

Thanks for any info.

EDIT:
I have found the solution using a combination of ::first-letter and ::before, like so...

```
<ul>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
</ul>

<ol>
  <li>1List Item 1</li>
  <li>2List Item 2</li>
</ol>

ol li::first-letter, ul li::before {
 ... // select's all ol and all ul list items
}

ul li::before {
  content: "*";
  ... // adds * as first letter for above
}
```

Comment: insert a span inside
`<li><span class="first-letter">L</span>ist Item</li>`

Comment: You have numbers in `unordered list` and what looks like custom icons in the `ordered list`. It's the wrong way around for starters. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list shows how to make custom `ol`s. > Seems I've misunderstood the question :)

Comment: @Harley, as stated I've used span, but with hundreds of list items it becomes a lot of excess code to put a span on each one.

Comment: @Gezzasa, good catch! I'm writing this on my phone at work in my free time so there'll likely be a few more mistakes ha ha. Basically the first character of each list item will be wrapped in a border and styled, I want to be able to select numbers, letters and characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think Javascript would be best here.

```
  var liArray = document.getElementsByTagName('li').innerHTML;

  for(i=0;i<liArray.length;i++){
    var buildString = '<span class="customStyle">';
    buildString += liArray[i].subString(0,1);
    buildString += '</span>';
    buildString += liArray[i].subString(1);
    liArray[i].innerHTML = buildString;
  }
```

To quickly explain the code. We start off by selecting all the list elements in your document and saving them into an array called "liArray".

Then we loop through that array in a for loop applying our code to each element.

Then we build a "new" string that takes the first character of each list element and wraps it in a span tag with the class "customStyle".

That will let you apply any styling you want to only the first character of the li just by adding the class "customStyle" to your css document.

Comment: Yeah I figured js would be the go, just wondering with all the selectors and pseudo selectors if I can do it solely with css.

Answer (score 0):

```
 body ul li:nth-child(odd){
background-color: #f22cf2;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that skip every 2nd list item?

Comment: Yes, u can use---> body ul li:nth-child(1n+0) {something:test;}

Comment: That select's the entire list item, rather than the first character of each list item. Though it's a handy thing to learn, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
ul li:nth-child(1) {
background: red;}

ol li:nth-child(1) {
background: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li>*List Item 1</li>
<li>*List Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ol>
<li>1List Item</li>
<li>1List Item</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That still select's the entire list item, where I only want to grab the first character, either 1 in ol or * in ul.