# <li> values as non-integers

Tags: html, html-lists

I have an ordered list. I already know I can change the displayed index of any given term with the `value` field:

```
<ol>
    <li value=6> ... </li>
    <li value=3> ... </li>
    <li value=99> ... </li>
</ol>
```

This displays something along the lines of:

```
6. ...
3. ...
99. ...
```

when it gets parsed.

What if I want my list index to be 6.5, or some other non-integer number? When I try

```
<li value="6.5"> ... </li>
```

it still just parses as

```
6. ...
```

Comment: li supports only integer numbers

Comment: Are there alternatives I can use to li, then?

Comment: What number should go after 6.5?

Comment: Ideally it goes 5, 6, 6.5, 7, ...

Comment: you can try to play with `li:before` content, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OL/LI tags support only integer numbers, so you cannot do it with pure HTML.

Here is example how you can use `li:before` CSS to put custom content.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(value);
}
li.half:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(value) ".5";
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li value=4> ... </li>
    <li value=6 class="half"> ... </li>
    <li value=10> ... </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for; with a little bit of position finagling, I got it to work how I wanted. Thanks!