# Use CSS to fake a custom ol label

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I would like to go beyond the ideas suggested in e.g. [How can you customize the numbers in an ordered list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list/31823704#31823704) and use a possibly complicated snippet of HTML to make my own labels in an ordered list.  For example:

```css
ol { padding-left: 10em }
li.item-cus-name {
  list-style-type: none
}
span.item-name {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute; left: -19.8em;
  width: 30em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>First item in an ordered list</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li class="item-cus-name"><span class="item-name">Label <em>ehags</em></span>Third</li>
    <li class="item-cus-name"><span class="item-name">c.</span>Fourth</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>More</li>
</ol>
```

What I'm trying to do is to let the `<span>` element stand in for the usual label, with the label text expanding out to the left (as happens when the usual numbering reaches double digits).  This solution is very brittle:

- If I have an extra long label which overflows the width I've set, it wraps, which I don't want.
- The exact position required by using `absolute` positioning needs constant fiddling (e.g. change the padding of the `ol` element in the example), and doesn't play nicely with, for example, increasing the size of the font.

Surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the text to wrap you can use `white-space:nowrap`... and positioning the "label" absolutely requires the `li` to be positioned `relative`.

If we always tell the label to be 100% `right` then the spacing between the label and the `li` is merely a matter of standard margin.

```css
ol {
  padding-left: 10em
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li.item-cus-name {
  list-style-type: none
}

span.item-name {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: .4em; /* adjust to your requirements */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First item in an ordered list</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li class="item-cus-name"><span class="item-name">Label <em>ehags.</em></span>Third</li>
  <li class="item-cus-name"><span class="item-name">c.</span>Fourth</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>More</li>
</ol>
```